# how to call a function after iframe form submit using submit() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

hi i am using jquery `submit()` function to submit iframe  . i want to add another event after completing the `submit()`

curently i use `$('.form').submit();`

i can not use `when() then()` because i am using jquery 1.3.2 , please help

Comment: what kind of event that you'd like to add? perhaps you want to use ajax (for form data submission) instead and do something after?

Comment: But doesn't "completing the submit" take you to another page? Or does it postback to the same page? Can you give a bit more background to what you're trying to do?

Comment: Are you taking about submit() callback?

Comment: i want to call another function after this completes

Answer (score 1):

@Kanishka Panamaldeniya the only way i see it happening without using ajax post kind of submit is once the form is submitted to the destination send out some response back to the page in the form of a get request by appending some variables to the url as additional params and catch them during an load event of the iframe page...dirty and disgraceful as it may sound its still a feasible option... hope it helps you in some way